# Creating a UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uipopovercontroller

I'm creating a popover in Xcode 4.3.
I don't get any error messages but when I click build and run and I press the button that is supposed to open the popover screen,  the app crashes and highlights in green a line in my code and says:

> Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1..

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

```
- (IBAction)popOver
{
    SecondView *secondview = [[SecondView alloc] init];
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:secondview];    

    [popover setDelegate:self];    

    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(801, 401, 300, 200) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 200)];   
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

Few suggestions here...

First, are you using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)? if yes you need to have an instance variable to control your `UIPopoverController`. For example:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController* popover;
```

if you are not using ARC create a `retain` one:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIPopoverController* popover;
```

In the first case you have to do this because if not, ARC will release for you the just created popover at the end of your IBAction. In addition you do this to have a reference for your popover. See NOTE. This is valid also if you don't use ARC.

*NOTE* At some point you could have the necessity to release the popover. For example in `- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController` do

```
self.popover = nil;
```

Then, if your `SecondView` is a `UIViewController` call it `SecondViewController`. But this is a simple naming suggestion.

Finally, the correct way for display the popover from the action sender (e.g a `UIButton`), instead of hardcode positions, could be:

```
- (IBAction)openPopover:(id)sender
{
    // create the popover here...

    UIButton* senderButton = (UIButton*)sender;

    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 200)];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:senderButton.bounds inView:senderButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
-(IBAction)showpop:(id)sender
{
UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popoverview];
[pop setDelegate:self];
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:popbutton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The SecondView that you're passing into `UIPopOverController` is a `UIView`. Make it a `UIViewController`, because, what `UIPopOverController` expects is a `UIViewController`.

-Suraj

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you simulate on iPad device

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
   // We are using an iPhone
    UIActionSheet *alertSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Where do you want to get your daily image?" delegate:(self) cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Library", nil];
   [alertSheet setTag:0];
   [alertSheet setDelegate:self];
   [alertSheet showFromTabBar:[[self tabBarController] tabBar]];
   [alertSheet release];
}else {
    // We are using an iPad
    /// here you should pass UIViewController inside the popover
    /// follow @flexaddicted notes to implement the popover
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below link for popover tutorial in ios

[UIPopOverController Tutorial](http://www.iostutorialjunction.com/2014/11/UIPopOverController-iPad.html)

Comment: can you also add some gist of the link in the answer

Comment: source code is also there in the tutorial but uploaded to G drive not on gist :)